# pyspark udf rlike condition in if error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark 2.1 scripting is pyspark scripting

My Dataframe is given below

dataframe name:df

a

Naveen

Naveen123

Now my output should be as

a

Naveen

I am using below udf for this

```
def fn(a):
    if((a==rlike("[0-9]"))|(a==' ')):
        return s

df.withColumn("FLG",fn("a")).show()
```

I am getting error like :global name 'rlike' is not defined

Please help me in crossing this hurdle

Comment: `s` is not defined in your function

Comment: s is an String value Marie I apologies it is < return 'S'>

Comment: So if the string is not proper (contains numbers or is a single space) you return a constant string value `"s"`. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `filter` not a `withColumn` that adds an extra column.

If you want strictly alphabetical :

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = df.withColumn("isCharString", df.a.rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
```

If you want to keep strings that don't have numbers

```py
df = df.withColumn("isCharString", ~df.a.rlike("[0-9]"))
```

The error you're getting using your function is because you use `rlike`as a standalone function which is not, it is an attribute for class pyspark columns. To rewrite your function in spark:

```py
df = df.withColumn("isCharString", psf.when(
        df.a.rlike("[0-9]")| (df.a == " "), 
        psf.lit("s")).otherwise(df.a))
```

Comment: Thanks Marie I have achieved this result I need in the form f function

Comment: You're not using `rlike` properly